Derivation of the number 600,000 in Zohar
I believe that there is a derivation of the 600,000 root souls of the Jewish people in the Zohar. My own Rav couldn't remember where exactly but he believes it is connected to the 6 emotional Sefirot (as is explained in Shaar Hagilgulim 17:1), and some sort of shlemut, through hitkalelut, of the Sefirot (it would have to be 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10, but that would need a justification).
Does anyone know of any source (doesn't have to be Zohar) that derives the 600,000 in this way (or similar)?

https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5643/is-the-zohar-kabbalah-sefirot-shittuf-heresy-avodah-zara-do-these-questions

Is this the one? :) See the source from Shir HaShirim in Zohar.

@Shmuel I don't follow the calculation I'm afraid? This seems to be the source, I'll go through it later bn: https://www.sefaria.org/Talmud_Eser_HaSefirot%2C_Section_III.15.1?vhe=Jerusalem,_1956-1966&lang=he

If I am following what Sulam is saying there, he says the Miluy of the names of the 12 tribes (perhaps when including the count for the letters) totals 600,000. The 12 names themselves are around 3,500. So making them into a Miluy might get you in the neighborhood.

"Now, there are only 600,000 soul
The [souls] all come from the six sefirot.
They correspond to the six days and the six directions of the world. They all come from the six sefirot." https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1287945/jewish/Six-Hundred-Thousand-Souls-171.htm Not the best source but relevant.

A relevant source is Sefer Hamaamarim 5626, p. 112:

אך כדי שיומשך הוא״ו של שם הוי׳ צריך שיהי׳ כלול מיו״ד ה״א של הוי׳ ואופן ההתכללות הוא כשהוא״ו כלול מיו״ד ה׳ פעמים הוא מספר ס״ר...‏
In order for the Vov of the Name Havayah to be drawn forth, it must inter-incorporate the Yud and Hei of Havayah. This incorporation is done when the Vov is multiplied by Yud, Hei times (i.e., 6 x 105), equaling 600,000...


This variation of "striking the stones" (a type of letter transformation we learn from Moshe Rabbeinu), which the Rashab is calling "Inclusion", is an indication of the teaching from the Zohar of how Israel and G-d are one.
